# Node.js Uncaught Exception Error: ECANCELED: operation

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm encountering an uncaught exception error in my Node.js application when trying to use unlinkSync. The error log shows Error: ECANCELED: operation canceled while attempting to unlink an MP4 file.

1. Using nodejs with express farmework
2. Storage location is on google cloud
3. Google instance storage is directly mounted on google cloud

Below is the error log:

```
1/2/2024 13:33:32 3586817 [ERROR] uncaughtException Error: ECANCELED: operation canceled, unlink '/var/www/mb-stream-store/live/9e44d2771c052d44058245eda6cb334689ca78cc/stream120240102133244.mp4'
    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1256:3)
    at unlinkFile (/var/www/nms/bin/app.js:209:6)
    at /var/www/nms/bin/app.js:230:5
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at processFiles (/var/www/nms/bin/app.js:227:28)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/www/nms/bin/app.js:122:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  errno: -125,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'ECANCELED',
  path: '/var/www/mb-stream-store/live/9e44d2771c052d44058245eda6cb334689ca78cc/stream120240102133244.mp4'
}
```

The error occurs in a function designed to unlink files after they have been processed. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
function unlinkFile(filePath) {
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error unlinking file:", err);
    }
}
```

This function is called within a loop to process multiple files. The application runs fine most of the time, but occasionally this error pops up.

- What causes the ECANCELED error in this context?
- Is there a way to prevent this error, or should I handle it differently?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show how you are importing libraries? Also share the minimal steps to reproduce. You can also have a look at this [sample snippet](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-http-form-data#code-sample) as well

Comment: @sher-singh Did you ever get past this?